# Access denied attempting to Manage Search service application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I click Manage on the Search Service application I get the access denied page.

ULS gives me nothing but:

"Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005"

We have upgraded through Search Foundation to Search Server Express to Search Server.

Our main web app is claims based authentication whereas our Central Administration is NTLM.

I found the following post which seems to be the same issue but there doesn't appear to be a solution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/2deafa72-6e91-4c43-aed3-895b24d504ac

Any advice on hunting down permissions issues of this type would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem.

The links web-part at the top of the Search Administration page was being auto-populated with links, some of them I didn't have access to.

I logged in with the farm account and closed this worse-than-useless web-part and all was well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but since I had no access to the "farm account" mentioned above, I had to remove this webpart programmatically.

Powershell:

```
$site = new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://path-to-central-admin:<portnumber>/")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$page = $web.Url + "/searchadministration.aspx"
$webpartmanager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
for($i=0;$i -lt $webpartmanager.WebParts.Count;$i++)
{
  if ($webpartmanager.WebParts[$i].title -eq "Shortcuts")
  {
     $webpartmanager.DeleteWebPart($webpartmanager.Webparts[$webpartmanager.WebParts[$i].ID])
  }
}
$web.Update();
$site.Dispose();
```

Save the script as a .ps1-file and call from the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell! :)